# Get or set css class value from external SVG file using javascript(jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have a svg file that contains some css classes in this format

```
  <style type="text/css" id="style1">
    <![CDATA[
      .fill1 {fill:#D2D3D5}
      .fill2 {fill:#A9ABAE}
      .fill3 {fill:#96989A}
    ]]>
  </style>
```

The svg file is displayed in an HTML file by using the following tag.

```
<object id="testObject" type="image/svg+xml" data="img/test.svg"></object>
```

Is there some way for me to get fill value of fill1,fill2 and fill3 using javascript or jquery. Also would it be possible to change these fill colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With generic Javascript, you can obtain the [`CSSStyleSheet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) object and manipulate any individual [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration):

```
// obtain document of object
var objectDoc = document.getElementById('testObject').contentDocument;
// obtain stylesheet
var stylesheet = objectDoc.getElementById('style1').sheet;

// find a certain rule
var rule2 = Array.from(stylesheet.cssRules).find(function (rule) {
    // make sure you reference a style rule and identify by selector string
    return rule.type === CSSRule.STYLE_RULE && rule.selectorText === '.fill2';
});

// get fill value
rule2.style.getPropertyValue('fill');
// set a different fill
rule2.style.setProperty('fill', '#676869');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get error "Uncaught TypeError: rule2.setProperty is not a function" when trying this

Comment: oops, sorry, there was a `CSSStyleRule.style` missing. See edit.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!